# Book with problem sets that will go well with Dennery and Krzywicki's Mathematics for Physicists?

Tags: mathematical-physics, resource-recommendations, education

Does anyone have any book/problem sets that would go well with Dennery and Krzywicki's [*Mathematics for Physicists*](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486691934.html)? I like the style of the book compared to usual texts like Riley, Arkfen, or Hobson and Bence, and would really like to study from it. The thing is this book has no problems sets and without doing problems, it's worthless to do a math methods course.

So, any pointers to other books, problem sets from professors, your own stuff would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please define what "go well with" means. Whether or not a problem set "goes well with" your favourite textbook is a matter of opinion, which you may not share.

Comment: I completely disagree with the closevotes on this question. Opinion-based questions, and their answers, do need to satisfy [specific criteria](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), but this question is well above that bar. Similarly, this is only a 'duplicate' of Kyle's link in the same way that apples and oranges are duplicates because they're both fruits; the proposed duplicate *explicitly* requests books away from Dennery's style.